# Javascript. Change a form option based on a previous one

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I'm trying to change the options that appear in my select box named session when a certain option is picked in my select box named movie.

Here's the script I've got so far.

```
<script>
            var optionList = document.getElementsByName("movie")[0];
            var movieList = ["AC", "CH", "AF", "RC"];

            for(var i = 0; i < movieList.length; i++){
                var movie = movieList[i];
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.textContent = movie;
                option.value = movie;
                optionList.appendChild(option);
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            var sessionList = document.getElementsByName("session")[0];
            var actionSession = ["WED-09", "THU-09", "FRI-09", "SAT-09", "SUN-09"];
            var childrenSession = ["MON-01", "TUE-01", "WED-06", "THU-06", "FRI-06", "SAT-12", "SUN-12"];
            var foreignSession = ["MON-06", "TUE-06", "SAT-06", "SUN-06"];
            var romanticSession = ["MON-09", "TUE-09", "WED-01", "THU-01", "FRI-01", "SAT-06", "SUN-06"];

            if(document.getElementsByName("movie")[0].value === movieList[0])
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < actionSession.length; i++){
                    var session = actionSession[i];
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.textContent = session;
                    option.value = session;
                    sessionList.appendChild(option);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing the Sessions to an object, like so:

```
var sessions = {
  "AC": ["WED-09", "THU-09", "FRI-09", "SAT-09", "SUN-09"],
  "CH": ["MON-01", "TUE-01", "WED-06", "THU-06", "FRI-06", "SAT-12", "SUN-12"],
  "AF": ["MON-06", "TUE-06", "SAT-06", "SUN-06"],
  "RC": ["MON-09", "TUE-09", "WED-01", "THU-01", "FRI-01", "SAT-06", "SUN-06"]
}
```

This way, you can use the `onchange` of your `select` tag to get the value of the selected `option` and reference the list of sessions for the appropriate movie list as such:

```
var category = document.getElementByName("movie").value;
var currentSession = sessions[category];

for(var i = 0; i < currentSession.length; i++){
  var session = currentSession[i];
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = session;
  option.value = session;
  sessionList.appendChild(option);
}
```

`Objects` in javascript can be referenced as `"key" => "value"` pairs simply by following the syntax:
    `object = { "key": value }`, and `value`'s type can be anything - even another `Object`!

You can even declare object keys like such:

```
var sessions = {};
sessions['AC'] = [...];
sessions['CH'] = [...];
sessions.AF = [...];
sessions.RC = [...];
```

That's right - all of the above declarations can be referenced as sessions['xx']

Hope this simplifies things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary mapping elements of `movieList` to lists of `<option>` elements, maybe?

You might call the dictionary `sessionOptions`. You would then change all the children of `#session` at once - so this would go in your `onchange` handler for `sessionList`:

```
var sessionList = document.getElementsByName("session")[0];
var chosenMovie = "..."; // "AC", for instance

// Remove all elements from sessionList
while(sessionList.firstChild) {
    sessionList.removeChild(sessionList.firstChild);
}

// Add the chosen movie options
var chosenMovieOptions = sessionOptions[chosenMovie];
for(var i = 0; i < chosenMovieOptions.length; i++) {
    sessionList.appendChild(chosenMovieOptions[i]);
}
```

You would also want to make a mapping of movie codes to session lists:

```
var SESSION_LISTS = {
    "AC": ["WED-09", "THU-09", "FRI-09", "SAT-09", "SUN-09"],
    "CH": ["MON-01", "TUE-01", "WED-06", "THU-06", "FRI-06", "SAT-12", "SUN-12"],
    "AF": ["MON-06", "TUE-06", "SAT-06", "SUN-06"],
    "RC": ["MON-09", "TUE-09", "WED-01", "THU-01", "FRI-01", "SAT-06", "SUN-06"]
};
```

Then, to build `sessionOptions`, for each "session string list" (such as `actionSession`), you would loop through the session list and create elements:

```
var currentSession = "..."; // currentSession is the current session list - "AC", for instance
var currentSessionOptions = SESSION_LISTS[currentSession];
sessionOptions[currentSession] = [];
for(var i = 0; i < currentSessionOptions.length; i++){
    var session = currentSessionOptions[i];
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = session;
    option.value = session;
    sessionOptions[currentSession].append(option);
}
```

But then you would do this for every sublist in `SESSION_LISTS`, so you would put this code in some initializer function:

```
var sessions = Object.keys(SESSION_LISTS);
for(var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
    currentSession = sessions[i];

    // the code snippet above
}
```